# Inbox tabs configuration per-device

Tags: gmail

I would have two inbox tabs configurations (Social, Forums, ...) , one for my PC and one for my Android device, in order to have a better data presentation on the last one.

I saw that the settings made by the configuration panel are per-account, so they are shared among each connected device.

Is it possibile to configure only the mobile phone account to show all the emails and the PC web client to show the desired tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a third-party client which doesn't support the tabs. That way all mail should go into the same inbox. As you said, the tab settings are per account and I don't think there is any way to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pseudo solution :

- PC => Web Client
- Android => Google InBox properly configured